# Can NDSolve be used for a system with number (+40) of equations?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have 42 coupled differential equations (6 of them are PDE's). My system has 6 objects and an object have 7 coupled equations. Since these objects are interacting with each other, their coupled equations also coupled with each other.

I can solve the system for 14 equations (2 objects). However, I can not run the code for 6 objects, NDSolve doesn't even give an error or warning. This is my first trial, and I am trying to make the simplest possible agent based model (i guess it can be referred as agent based modelling).

Is it possible to solve such a system with MMA? If so how can it be done? My final question, is there a different terminology for systems with high number of equations?

Any help would be appreciated.

The code:

````
Clear["Global`*"]
(*SET UP*)
tmax = 2500;
(*INITIAL CONDITIONS*)

inical = SetPrecision[ 0.200165185171545551`5. , 5];
iniope = 1/(1 + inical^2);
\[Mu]\[Mu] = SetPrecision[0.5500000, 5]
\[Mu]0 = SetPrecision[0.5155877999949406`, 5]
(*PARAMETERS*)
Dc = 20;
kflux = 8.1;
l = 20;(*--------*)
b = 0.111 // Rationalize;
k1 = 0.7;
\[Gamma] = 2.0;
k\[Gamma] = 0.1;
\[Beta] =(*0 *)0.02;
\[Tau]n = 2.0;
k2 = 0.7;
K1 = ((kflux \[Tau]n)/k1);
\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] = ((\[Tau]n \[Gamma] 0.9)/k1);
\[CapitalGamma] = ((\[Tau]n \[Gamma] )/k1);
T = (\[Gamma]*\[Tau]n)/k1;
K = (k\[Gamma]/k1);
K2 = k2/k1;
B = \[Beta]/k1;
D0 = Dc \[Tau]n/l^2;
Dp0 = Dp \[Tau]n /l^2;
Dp = 300;
\[Mu]1 = 0.433;
 kp = 0.02;
(*q=-3.4;*)
xxx = -0.1;
qqq = -0.4;
Q1 = 0.09;
Q2 = 0.5;
ttt = 0.6;
zzz = -1.2;
sol = NDSolve[{
  D[v1o1[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o1[t, x], x, 
      x] +((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o1[t, x])/(1 + v1o1[t, x])) v2o1[t, 
         x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o1[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o1[t, x])) + 
    B -10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o1[t, x]) v1o1[t, x],
  D[v2o1[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o1[t, x]^2) - v2o1[t, x],
  D[v3o1[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o1[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o1[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o1[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*((v4o2[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o2[t, x])), 
  D[v4o2[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*(v4o2[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o2[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o2[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*(v4o2[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o2[t, x]),
  D[v6o2[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o2[t, x])),
  D[v7o2[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o2[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o2[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o2[t, x])),
  D[v1o2[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o2[t, x], x, 
      x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o2[t, x])/(1 + v1o2[t, x])) v2o2[
       t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o2[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o2[t, x])) + B - 
    10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o2[t, x]) v1o2[t, x],
  D[v2o2[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o2[t, x]^2) - v2o2[t, x],
  D[v3o2[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o2[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o2[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o2[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o1[t, x])), 
  D[v4o1[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*(v4o1[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o1[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o1[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*(v4o1[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o1[t, x]),
  D[v6o1[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o1[t, x])),
  D[v7o1[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o1[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o1[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o1[t, x])),
  (**)
  D[v1o3[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o3[t, x], x, 
      x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o3[t, x])/(1 + v1o3[t, x])) v2o3[t, 
       x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o3[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o3[t, x])) + B - 
    10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o3[t, x]) v1o3[t, x],
  D[v2o3[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o3[t, x]^2) - v2o3[t, x],
  D[v3o3[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o3[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o3[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o3[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o4[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o4[t, x])), 
  D[v4o4[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*(v4o4[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o4[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o4[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*(v4o4[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o4[t, x]),
  D[v6o4[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o4[t, x])),
  D[v7o4[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o4[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o4[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o4[t, x])),
  D[v1o4[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o4[t, x], x, 
      x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o4[t, x])/(1 + v1o4[t, x])) v2o4[
       t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o4[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o4[t, x])) + B - 
    10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o4[t, x]) v1o4[t, x],
  D[v2o4[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o4[t, x]^2) - v2o4[t, x],
  D[v3o4[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o4[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o4[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o4[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o3[t, x])), 
  D[v4o3[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*(v4o3[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o3[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o3[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*(v4o3[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o3[t, x]),
  D[v6o3[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o3[t, x])),
  D[v7o3[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o3[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o3[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o3[t, x])),
  (**)
  D[v1o5[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o5[t, x], x, 
      x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o5[t, x])/(1 + v1o5[t, x])) v2o5[t, 
       x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o5[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o5[t, x])) + B - 
    10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o5[t, x]) v1o5[t, x],
  D[v2o5[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o5[t, x]^2) - v2o5[t, x],
  D[v3o5[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o5[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o5[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o5[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*((v4o6[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o6[t, x])), 
  D[v4o6[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*(v4o6[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o6[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o6[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*(v4o6[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o6[t, x]),
  D[v6 o6[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o6[t, x])),
  D[v7o6[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o6[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o6[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o6[t, x])),
  D[v1o6[t, x], t] ==  
   D0 D[v1o6[t, x], x, 
      x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o6[t, x])/(1 + v1o6[t, x])) v2o6[
       t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o6[t, x])/(K + 
       v1o6[t, x])) + B - 
    10^zzz(*Q110^xxx/\[Tau]n*)(v7o6[t, x]) v1o6[t, x],
  D[v2o6[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o6[t, x]^2) - v2o6[t, x],
  D[v3o6[t, x], 
    t] == (0.001 +10^ttt (v1o6[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o6[t, x]^2)) - 
     0.005*(v3o6[t, x]) - 
     0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*((v4o5[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
     0.1*(v5o5[t, x])), 
  D[v4o5[t, x], 
    t] == (-0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*(v4o5[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v4o5[t, x]) + 0.007),
  D[v5o5[t, x], t] == 
   0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*(v4o5[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 
    0.005*(v5o5[t, x]),
  D[v6o5[t, x], t] == ( 0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o5[t, x])),
  D[v7o5[t, x], t] == ( 
    0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o5[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o5[t, x])^2)) - 
     0.005*(v7o5[t, x])),
  v2o1[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o1[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o1[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o1[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o1[0, x] == 0,
  v4o1[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o1[0, x] == 0,
  v6o1[0, x] == 0,
  v7o1[0, x] == 0,
  v2o2[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o2[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o2[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o2[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o2[0, x] == 0,
  v4o2[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o2[0, x] == 0,
  v6o2[0, x] == 0,
  v7o2[0, x] == 0,
  (**)
  v2o3[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o3[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o3[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o3[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o3[0, x] == 0,
  v4o3[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o3[0, x] == 0,
  v6o3[0, x] == 0,
  v7o3[0, x] == 0,
  v2o4[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o4[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o4[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o4[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o4[0, x] == 0,
  v4o4[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o4[0, x] == 0,
  v6o4[0, x] == 0,
  v7o4[0, x] == 0,
  (**)
  v2o5[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o5[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o5[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o5[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o5[0, x] == 0,
  v4o5[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o5[0, x] == 0,
  v6o5[0, x] == 0,
  v7o5[0, x] == 0,
  v2o6[0, x] == iniope,
  v1o6[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2 , inical],
  v1o6[t, -200] == inical ,
  v1o6[t, 200] == inical ,
  v3o6[0, x] == 0,
  v4o6[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
  v5o6[0, x] == 0,
  v6o6[0, x] == 0,
  v7o6[0, x] == 0
  },
 {v1o1, v2o1, v3o1, v4o1, v5o1, v6o1, v7o1, v1o2, v2o2, v3o2, v4o2, 
  v5o2, v6o2, v7o2(**), v1o3, v2o3, v3o3, v4o3, v5o3, v6o3, v7o3, 
  v1o4, v2o4, v3o4, v4o4, v5o4, v6o4, v7o4,(**)v1o5, v2o5, v3o5, v4o5,
   v5o5, v6o5, v7o5, v1o6, v2o6, v3o6, v4o6, v5o6, v6o6, v7o6}, {t, 0,
   tmax}, {x, -200, 200},
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MaxPoints" -> 101}}]
Plot[{Evaluate[{v3o1[t, 0]} /. sol], Evaluate[{v3o2[t, 0]} /. sol], 
  Evaluate[{v3o3[t, 0]} /. sol], Evaluate[{v3o4[t, 0]} /. sol], 
  Evaluate[{v3o5[t, 0]} /. sol], Evaluate[{v3o6[t, 0]} /. sol]}, {t, 
  0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```
````

Comment: in theory, with a numerical solver, having 16 equations vs. 32 vs. 64, should not make any difference (except for memory and time). As to why NDSolve can't solve your system when you add more equations, it is hard to know, since you did not show an example or say what error or what happens exactly. does it hang? what does it do?  Without an example, hard to say.

Comment: @Nasser you are right, I added the code.

Comment: @confused Why don't you use matrix form for 6 objects?

Comment: I have not seen an example where `NDSolve` solves coupled PDEs + ODEs.  I have seen `NDSolve` complain if all dependent variables do not all have the same arguments in the same order.  I have seen a PDE+ODE system in which the ODE was recast as a PDE (`NDSolve` solves the same ODE at each point in the spatial discretization)

Comment: @confused After some debugging this code works. What actually  this question about?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I didn't thought about that, and I have never used it. You think computing on a  a 42 x 42 matrix would be easier?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Only 1 time it run, and didn't finish running in my computer. On other trials, it stopped running on its own without any warning etc.

Comment: @MichaelE2 here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237215/ndsolve-for-ode-pde-problem I have a coupled PDEs + ODEs and I asked whether ```NDSolve``` be used for this problem, or do you know\suggest any other approach for coupled PDE - ODE systems. You also commented to my question "Your ```NDSolve``` runs without complaint. What's the problem?"  I guess, I was "recasting", and continued to recast.

Comment: @confused  What `$Version` do you run?

Comment: @confused Which is the ODE? I see only PDEs in the `NDSolve` code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 First equation `D[v1o1[t, x], t] == 
 D0 D[v1o1[t, x], x, 
    x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o1[t, x])/(1 + v1o1[t, x])) v2o1[t, 
     x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o1[t, x])/(K + 
      v1o1[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o1[t, x]) v1o1[t, x], 
D[v2o1[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o1[t, x]^2) - v2o1[t, x]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev 12.1, I ran the code now it worked. But it didn't worked before  why this happened? It stopped reacting an hour ago so I quit the kernel. Can quitting kernel solve this? I am so so sorry for taking everyones time.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That's a PDE, isn't it? An ODE has the form `u'[t] == F[t, u[t]`....I think we should be strict in our definitions when dealing with a computer program, or at least as strict as the program.

Comment: @confused Quitting the kernel is known to fix inexplicable problems. If it works, it should be because of a forgotten definition that wasn't cleared.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought if it is having only a time derivative no matter what is the number of arguments it is an ODE. I see that's "recasting".  I think other solvers like FEniCS doesn't work like that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 My bad didn't know that sorry.  Thank you all for sharing your time.

Comment: Quitting the kernel could also reset a bug. Like rebooting the computer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging this code works on v12.0 and 12.2 as well

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*SET UP*)
tmax = 2500;
(*INITIAL CONDITIONS*)

inical = SetPrecision[0.200165185171545551`5., 5];
iniope = 1/(1 + inical^2);
\[Mu]\[Mu] = SetPrecision[0.5500000, 5];
\[Mu]0 = SetPrecision[0.5155877999949406`, 5];
(*PARAMETERS*)
Dc = 20;
kflux = 8.1;
l = 20;(*--------*)b = 0.111 // Rationalize;
k1 = 0.7;
\[Gamma] = 2.0;
k\[Gamma] = 0.1;
\[Beta] =(*0*)0.02;
\[Tau]n = 2.0;
k2 = 0.7;
K1 = ((kflux \[Tau]n)/k1);
\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] = ((\[Tau]n \[Gamma] 0.9)/k1);
\[CapitalGamma] = ((\[Tau]n \[Gamma])/k1);
T = (\[Gamma]*\[Tau]n)/k1;
K = (k\[Gamma]/k1);
K2 = k2/k1;
B = \[Beta]/k1;
D0 = Dc \[Tau]n/l^2;
Dp0 = Dp \[Tau]n/l^2;
Dp = 300;
\[Mu]1 = 0.433;
kp = 0.02;
(*q=-3.4;*)
xxx = -0.1;
qqq = -0.4;
Q1 = 0.09;
Q2 = 0.5;
ttt = 0.6;
zzz = -1.2; var = {v1o1, v2o1, v3o1, v4o1, v5o1, v6o1, v7o1, v1o2, 
  v2o2, v3o2, v4o2, v5o2, v6o2, v7o2, v1o3, v2o3, v3o3, v4o3, v5o3, 
  v6o3, v7o3, v1o4, v2o4, v3o4, v4o4, v5o4, v6o4, v7o4, v1o5, v2o5, 
  v3o5, v4o5, v5o5, v6o5, v7o5, v1o6, v2o6, v3o6, v4o6, v5o6, v6o6, 
  v7o6};
eq = {D[v1o1[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o1[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o1[t, x])/(1 + v1o1[t, x])) v2o1[t, 
        x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o1[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o1[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o1[t, x]) v1o1[t, x], 
   D[v2o1[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o1[t, x]^2) - v2o1[t, x], 
   D[v3o1[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o1[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o1[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o1[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*((v4o2[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o2[t, x])), 
   D[v4o2[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*(v4o2[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o2[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o2[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o1[t, x])*(v4o2[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o2[t, x]), 
   D[v6o2[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o2[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o2[t, x])), 
   D[v7o2[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o2[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o2[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o2[t, x])), 
   D[v1o2[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o2[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o2[t, x])/(1 + v1o2[t, x])) v2o2[
        t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o2[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o2[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o2[t, x]) v1o2[t, x], 
   D[v2o2[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o2[t, x]^2) - v2o2[t, x], 
   D[v3o2[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o2[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o2[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o2[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o1[t, x])), 
   D[v4o1[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*(v4o1[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o1[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o1[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o2[t, x])*(v4o1[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o1[t, x]), 
   D[v6o1[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o1[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o1[t, x])), 
   D[v7o1[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o1[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o1[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o1[t, x])),(**)
   D[v1o3[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o3[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o3[t, x])/(1 + v1o3[t, x])) v2o3[t, 
        x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o3[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o3[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o3[t, x]) v1o3[t, x], 
   D[v2o3[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o3[t, x]^2) - v2o3[t, x], 
   D[v3o3[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o3[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o3[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o3[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o4[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o4[t, x])), 
   D[v4o4[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*(v4o4[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o4[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o4[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o3[t, x])*(v4o4[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o4[t, x]), 
   D[v6o4[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o4[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o4[t, x])), 
   D[v7o4[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o4[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o4[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o4[t, x])), 
   D[v1o4[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o4[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o4[t, x])/(1 + v1o4[t, x])) v2o4[
        t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o4[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o4[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o4[t, x]) v1o4[t, x], 
   D[v2o4[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o4[t, x]^2) - v2o4[t, x], 
   D[v3o4[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o4[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o4[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o4[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*((v4o1[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o3[t, x])), 
   D[v4o3[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*(v4o3[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o3[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o3[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o4[t, x])*(v4o3[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o3[t, x]), 
   D[v6o3[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o3[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o3[t, x])), 
   D[v7o3[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o3[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o3[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o3[t, x])),(**)
   D[v1o5[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o5[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]0) K1 ((b + v1o5[t, x])/(1 + v1o5[t, x])) v2o5[t, 
        x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o5[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o5[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o5[t, x]) v1o5[t, x], 
   D[v2o5[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o5[t, x]^2) - v2o5[t, x], 
   D[v3o5[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o5[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o5[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o5[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*((v4o6[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o6[t, x])), 
   D[v4o6[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*(v4o6[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o6[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o6[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o5[t, x])*(v4o6[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o6[t, x]), 
   D[v6o6[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o6[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o6[t, x])), 
   D[v7o6[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o6[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o6[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o6[t, x])), 
   D[v1o6[t, x], t] == 
    D0 D[v1o6[t, x], x, 
       x] + ((\[Mu]\[Mu]) K1 ((b + v1o6[t, x])/(1 + v1o6[t, x])) v2o6[
        t, x]) - ((\[CapitalGamma]\[CapitalGamma] v1o6[t, x])/(K + 
         v1o6[t, x])) + B - 10^zzz (v7o6[t, x]) v1o6[t, x], 
   D[v2o6[t, x], t] == 1/(1 + v1o6[t, x]^2) - v2o6[t, x], 
   D[v3o6[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + 10^ttt (v1o6[t, x]^2/(1/k1^2 + v1o6[t, x]^2)) - 
      0.005*(v3o6[t, x]) - 
      0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*((v4o5[t, x] + v4o3[t, x])/2) + 
      0.1*(v5o5[t, x])), 
   D[v4o5[t, x], 
     t] == (-0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*(v4o5[t, x]) + 0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 
      0.005*(v4o5[t, x]) + 0.007), 
   D[v5o5[t, x], t] == 
    0.001*(v3o6[t, x])*(v4o5[t, x]) - 0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 
     0.005*(v5o5[t, x]), 
   D[v6o5[t, x], t] == (0.1*(v5o5[t, x]) - 0.005*(v6o5[t, x])), 
   D[v7o5[t, x], 
     t] == (0.001 + ((0.1*(v6o5[t, x])^2)/(1 + (v6o5[t, x])^2)) - 
      0.005*(v7o5[t, x]))};
icbc = {v2o1[0, x] == iniope, 
   v1o1[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], v1o1[t, -200] == inical,
    v1o1[t, 200] == inical, v3o1[0, x] == 0, v4o1[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
   v5o1[0, x] == 0, v6o1[0, x] == 0, v7o1[0, x] == 0, 
   v2o2[0, x] == iniope, v1o2[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], 
   v1o2[t, -200] == inical, v1o2[t, 200] == inical, v3o2[0, x] == 0, 
   v4o2[0, x] == 0.1,(**)v5o2[0, x] == 0, v6o2[0, x] == 0, 
   v7o2[0, x] == 0,(**)v2o3[0, x] == iniope, 
   v1o3[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], v1o3[t, -200] == inical,
    v1o3[t, 200] == inical, v3o3[0, x] == 0, v4o3[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
   v5o3[0, x] == 0, v6o3[0, x] == 0, v7o3[0, x] == 0, 
   v2o4[0, x] == iniope, v1o4[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], 
   v1o4[t, -200] == inical, v1o4[t, 200] == inical, v3o4[0, x] == 0, 
   v4o4[0, x] == 0.1,(**)v5o4[0, x] == 0, v6o4[0, x] == 0, 
   v7o4[0, x] == 0,(**)v2o5[0, x] == iniope, 
   v1o5[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], v1o5[t, -200] == inical,
    v1o5[t, 200] == inical, v3o5[0, x] == 0, v4o5[0, x] == 0.1,(**)
   v5o5[0, x] == 0, v6o5[0, x] == 0, v7o5[0, x] == 0, 
   v2o6[0, x] == iniope, v1o6[0, x] == If[-20 < x < 20, 2, inical], 
   v1o6[t, -200] == inical, v1o6[t, 200] == inical, v3o6[0, x] == 0, 
   v4o6[0, x] == 0.1,(**)v5o6[0, x] == 0, v6o6[0, x] == 0, 
   v7o6[0, x] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eq, icbc}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -200, 200}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxPoints" -> 101}}];
```

Visualization of numerical solution

```
Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[var[[i]][t, x] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, -200, 200}, 
  PlotLabel -> var[[i]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], {i, Length[var]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]